# How do I determine if an entity exists in the current data context?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

For example, say I am either creating or fetching some entities that I later plan to insert, update, or discard:

```
foreach (var foo in foos) {
    if (foo.condition)
        _myEntityCollection.Add(new Some_Entity_Type());
    else
        _myEntityCollection.Add(dc.Some_Entity_Types
          .Where(t => t.ID == someID).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

When it comes time to, say, revert, I may do this:

```
// Exception gets thrown here if entity didn't exist in data context
_myEntityCollection.ForEach(t => dc.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, t));
```

I want to be able to iterate through `_myEntityCollection` and determine if the entity was one I fetched, or if it was a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the object state manager to test if the object context is aware of a specific entity.

```
var objectStateManager = context.ObjectStateManager;

ObjectStateEntry temp;
var result = objectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(myEntity, out temp);
```

*UPDATE*

The code from above works for the Entity Framework but the question concerns LINQ to SQL. You could try to inspect the [`ChangeSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.changeset.aspx) returned by [`DataContext.GetChangeSet()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx). It contains three lists for added, deleted and updated entities.

Comment: I should have specified that I'm using a Linq DataContext, not an ObjectContext (with which I'm not very familiar). Do you know if there is a carryover for DataContext?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how this could be translated from Entity Framework to LINQ to SQL - I used LINQ to SQL only once some years ago and I am not familiar with the internals.

Comment: I (probably) found a solution - updating my answer.

Comment: That sure does add a lot of overhead.  I'll probably end up just creating a wrapper to keep track of whether or not the entity exists in the context yet.  Thanks!